# Are Starch, Amylose and, Amylopectin reducing sugars?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, carbohydrates

Amylose and Amylopectin;
As per the information I've learnt, Amylose is considered a reducing sugar but Amylopectin is not because Amylose has a free "reducing end" which Amylopectin lacks, I fail to understand why we don't use a similar argument for Amylopectin as the Haworth structures for both are vastly similar, why is that that we consider a "reducing end" for Amylose but don't do the same for Amylopectin?

Starch;
Consists of both Amylose and Amylopectin, if Amylose is truly a reducing sugar, shouldn't the presence of Amylose in Starch be sufficient to classify Starch as a reducing sugar? or is it that we consider Starch non-reducing due to some other factors?

Comment: Are you sure that amylose is a reducing sugar, and that amylopectin is not ? Amylose contains more alcoholic groups than amylopectin. Is it sufficient to state that amylose is reducing and amylopectin not ?

Comment: In the institution I study at, our professor seemed to have taught us that but on clarification, he reiterated that Amylose is NOT a reducing sugar and neither is Amylopectin, he also mentioned something about Starch-Iodide reactions and that even in those reactions, starch wouldn't play much of a role; He concluded that Starch, Amylose and, Amylopectin are all non-reducing sugars

Comment: @Maurice The term "reducing" is used in a limited sense here to designate substances that have an aldehyde group or a group that reacts like an aldehyde.

Answer (score 2):

> [OP] As per the information I've learnt, Amylose is considered a reducing sugar but Amylopectin is not because Amylose has a free "reducing end" which Amylopectin lacks

It would be nice to know the source of this statement because it does not sound right.

> [OP in comments] In the institution I study at, our professor seemed to have taught us that but on clarification, he reiterated that Amylose is NOT a reducing sugar and neither is Amylopectin, he also mentioned something about Starch-Iodide reactions and that even in those reactions, starch wouldn't play much of a role; He concluded that Starch, Amylose and, Amylopectin are all non-reducing sugars

Both amylose and amylopectin are made up of glucose building blocks. The aldehyde (or hemiacetal in the ring form) of glucose is called "reducing" because it reacts positive in Fehling's, Benedict's, or Tollen's test. When a glucose forms a glycosidic bond, it is no longer considered reducing because it does not react in these tests.

All the sugar linkages in amylose and amylopectin involve a hemiacetal group of one sugar, and a hydroxyl group of the other sugar. It turns out that both amylose and amylopectin, even though they contain thousands of glucose units, have a single reducing end each. Whether you can detect that single reducing end with one of the mentioned assays depends on concentration of these reducing ends; however, the signal will be weak if not absent.

> [OP] Starch; Consists of both Amylose and Amylopectin, if Amylose is truly a reducing sugar, shouldn't the presence of Amylose in Starch be sufficient to classify Starch as a reducing sugar?

If one (or both) of the components have some property, then the mixture should show that property as well, unless there is some interaction or inhibition of the assays.  Technically, starch is not a sugar but a mixture of sugars (or more accurately, polysaccharides).

Answer (score -2):

### Amylose vs. Amylopectin – Reducing Ends:

Amylose is a linear polymer of glucose units linked by α(1→4) linkages. It has a reducing end due to its free anomeric carbon and a non-reducing end. In contrast, amylopectin is a branched polymer of glucose with α(1→4) linkages and branch points created by α(1→6) linkages. Despite having many non-reducing ends, it has only one reducing end. The difference between them is not based on the Haworth structures but on their linkage patterns and molecular architecture. Both are reducing sugars, but amylose, being simpler and linear, is often more associated with its reducing property.

### Starch as a Reducing Sugar:

Starch, composed of amylose and amylopectin, possesses reducing properties. However, it doesn't elicit a pronounced positive reaction with Benedict’s test. This muted response is attributed to the limited presence of reducing sugar molecules, which are situated only at the ends of the carbohydrate chains. The term "reducing sugar" encompasses a spectrum: certain molecules demonstrate more potent reducing characteristics due to their abundance of free reducing ends. Both amylose (linear) and amylopectin (branched) possess reducing ends. So, while starch can technically be categorized as a reducing sugar, its reactivity is so minimal that it is almost indistinguishable from the background, leading many to treat starch as a non-reducing sugar for practical purposes.

**References:**

ScienceDirect. (n.d.). Amylopectin. Retrieved from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/amylopectin

ScienceDirect. (n.d.). Amylose. Retrieved from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/amylose

Scottish Sensory Centre. (n.d.). Benedict’s solution. Retrieved from [https://www.ssc.education.ed.ac.uk/BSL/chemistry/Benedictsolutiond.html#:~:text=(2.04)%20Benedict's%20solution%20turns%20orange,colour%3B%20it%20should%20remain%20blue](https://www.ssc.education.ed.ac.uk/BSL/chemistry/Benedictsolutiond.html#:%7E:text=(2.04)%20Benedict%27s%20solution%20turns%20orange,colour%3B%20it%20should%20remain%20blue).

Byju's. (n.d.). Limitations of Benedict’s Test. Retrieved from [https://byjus.com/chemistry/limitations-of-benedicts-test/#:~:text=Why%20isn't%20starch%20detected,that%20has%20a%20negative%20effect](https://byjus.com/chemistry/limitations-of-benedicts-test/#:%7E:text=Why%20isn%27t%20starch%20detected,that%20has%20a%20negative%20effect).

Comment: @MetalStorm please raise a flag if you find something you suspect is amiss.